# Как запомнить значение в переменную при вызове subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Есть код

```
topic = "asde"
commandlisten = ("echo", ""+topic+"")
try:
    commandOutput = subprocess.run(commandlisten, timeout=1) 
    print (commandOutput)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print ('asd')
```

при его выполнении выводит

```
asde
CompletedProcess(args=('echo', 'asde'), returncode=0)
```

как сохранить вывод командной строки в переменную то есть переменная commandOutput была равна asde

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо использовать [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) и [subprocess.Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

```
import subprocess

args = ["echo", "asde"]
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = process.communicate(timeout=1)
print(data[0].decode('utf-8'))
```

Метод communicate позволит нам связываться с созданным нами процессом. Говорят, можно даже передать процессу ввод.
После того, как процесс завершится, в `data` будет кортеж, состоящий из двух элементов - содержимое stdout и stderr, бинарной строкой.

Comment: А аргумент timeout в Popen отсутствует?                                            process = subprocess.Popen(commandlisten, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, timeout=1)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'

Comment: Похоже, что да. В communicate есть, кажется, то, что нужно

Comment: А я же правильно понимаю, timeout убивает запущенный процесс?

Comment: В документации написано, что просто бросается исключение `TimeoutExpired`, отловив которое, можно попробовать вызывать `communicate` снова и попытать счастье. Есть специальный метод [subprocess.Popen.kill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill)